# eclipse can't find main class

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, program-entry-point

I am working on a project requiring using the Picasso Query Optimizer Analysis Tools, I am trying to configure the java source files onto eclipse EE Luna. However, I kept getting the error message that:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class iisc.dsl.picasso.server.Picasso_Server.
```

I tried the methods mentioned online and can't solve it by now, I also paste the classpath file with the post.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="./src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add the Picasso Query Optimizer Analysis Tools to the classpath? (do it from inside Eclipse. don't edit the classpath file, you'll just end up getting it wrong and breaking the project)

Comment: Try to edit this line manually : <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a project based classpath functionality. Keep all the jars you'd like to be imported in a folder and from eclipse, right click on your project --> properties --> java build path --> libraries (tab)-->add external jars.

Select all the jars you'd like to import to your project.

Try cleaning your project and then running it after this